# iPhone doesn't create sqlite db file

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i have a problem in the creation of my db file. I'm using this function:

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded {
    // Testing for existence
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];

    NSLog(@"%@", writableDBPath);

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"The file was here");
        return;
    }

    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to
    // the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:DATABASE_NAME];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath
                                   toPath:writableDBPath
                                    error:&error];
    NSLog(@"New file created");

    if(!success)
    {
        NSAssert1(0,@"Failed to create writable database file with Message : '%@'.",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Executing this always generate the log "New file created", but if i point my finder to the db path i find an empty folder: the file was not created!

What is the problem in your opinion?

(I have another app using the same function, and works well!)

UPDATE:

If i use the "go to folder" function of finder and paste in the `defaultDBPath`, it tells me that i don't have the privileges required to access the folder

Comment: What is string value of DATABASE_NAME    ?

Comment: #define DATABASE_NAME @"villaggio.db"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved it... very stupid of me!

Simply i were setting the DATABASE_NAME to "villaggio.`db`", while my real db was named "villaggio.`sqlite`" !!!

=D

Answer (score 1):

Can't instantly spot a problem with your general code, but note that the `NSLog(@"New file created");` will always occur as you're not checking `success`.  Like your test for the file being there, you need to check `success`:

```
if (success)
    NSLog(@"New file created");
```

Then you will at least be properly testing whether it thinks a file is created.  If not, double-check your `defaultDBPath` and `writableDBPath` variables.